# IP Address when access website on Remote Computer

Tags: teamviewer

Can you please advise me on this,
All the web sites visited on remote computer, can that be traced?

I have a office computer say COMP1 and Home Computer COMP2.
If i access any websites on COMP2 (remote), can that be traced on COMP1(office).

On my TeamViewer Under Computers&Contacts I have added COMP1 and COMP2.
Accessing COMP2 from COMP1, but there is monitor on COMP1.
So sites visited on COMP2 can be traced on COMP1(office)?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: possible if  there is a screen capture software installed in COMP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless COMP2 and COMP1 are on the same network or are managed by the same domain. then it is unlikely that they can trace what you browse on COMP2 whilst your at work using COMP1.

HOWEVER, if you are using a internet browser such as Google chrome which takes your browsing history with you from device to device. (home computer, work computer, mobile). that information is then temporarily stored on your work computer and if they decided to look for it they have every right since you have brought that information onto THEIR network.

Alternatively just don't browse anything inappropriate at work?>